# HtmlWebpackPlugin erase template div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I follow this example(http://courses.reactjsprogram.com/courses/reactjsfundamentals/lectures/760301) to start one reactj app, so this is my 
webpack.config.js

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  tempalte : __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename : 'index.html',
  inject : 'body'
})
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './app/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path : __dirname + '/dist',
    filename : "index_bundle.js"
  },
  module : {
    loaders :[
      {test: /\.js$/, include: __dirname + '/app', loader: "babel-loader"}
    ]
  },
  plugins : [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]
}
```

And this is my index.html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> teste</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my index.html generated by webpack

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Webpack App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script src="index_bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Note: my   are removed, so when I try to run my app I got the error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

How can I fix to don`t remove my div?
I using 
"babel-core": "^6.7.6",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
"webpack": "^1.13.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"

tks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A typo in the `template` key in your configuration means that it is using a default template and not the one you were trying to include. The default behavior makes this error difficult to spot.

`tempalte : __dirname + '/app/index.html'`
should be
`template : __dirname + '/app/index.html'`

Comment: Nice catch, just make the difference a bit more obvious.

Comment: tks and sorry.. my bad :)